# How do I restart loop once it removes a nonselected item in a listbox?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

On the listbox, an user has an option to add dates.  I am trying to also give the user the option to remove dates by clicking on a button. My code looks like this:

```
Private Sub RemoveDate_Click()
    Dim objSpecifyDates As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Set objSpecifyDates = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("SpecifyDatesListBox").Object
    If objSpecifyDates.listCount = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        For i = 0 To objSpecifyDates.listCount - 1
            If Not objSpecifyDates.Selected(i) Then
                objSpecifyDates.RemoveItem (i)
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem with this code is once an item is removed, it returns error at the last loop since that index became nonexistent. Is there a way to restart the loop once it removes an item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When removing things like this you need to move backwards through the collection.

```
For i = objSpecifyDates.listCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    ...
Next i
```